# Most efficient way to replace NAs in a data frame based on a subset of other row factors (using median as an estimate) in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I would like to estimate the values of a numeric variable in a data frame based on the median of the same variable given other factors. I would then like to replace the NA's for the numeric Variable with these estimates.

I have a data frame like this:

```
Fac1   Fac2   Var1
A      a      20
A      b      30
B      a      5
B      b      10
.
.
.
```

I have used the agregate function to find these medians for each combination of factors:

```
A a = 22
A b = 28
B a = 12
B b = 8
```

So any NA's in Var1 would be replaced with the corresponding median based on the combinations of the factors.

I understand that this may be done by replacing the missing values for each subset of the data individually, however that would become tedious quickly given more than two factors.
I was wondering if there are some more efficient ways to get this result.

Comment: Don't calculate the medians separately. Use `Hmisc::impute` with a split-apply-combine function of your choice.

Comment: To add to Roland's comment, you might want to look into packages such as dplyr or data.table for data manipulation/cleaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a sample data but based on your question, I think this should work.

As @Roland mentioned no need to calculate `median` separately.

Assuming your dataframe as `df`. For every group (here `Fac1` and `Fac2`) we calculate the median removing the `NA` values. Further we select only the indices which has `NA` values and replace it by its groups median value.

```
df$Var1[is.na(df$Var1)] <- ave(df$Var1,df$Fac1, df$Fac2, FUN=function(x) 
                                  median(x, na.rm = T)[is.na(df$Var1)]
```

**UPDATE**

On request of OP adding some information about `ave` function.

The first parameter in `ave` is the one on which you want to do any operation. So here the first parameter is `Var1` for which we want to find the `median`. All the other parameters following that are the grouping variables. It could be any number. Here the grouping variables we have are `Fac1` and `Fac2`. Now comes the function which we want to apply on our first parameter (`Var1`) for every group (`Fac1` and `Fac2`) which we have defined in the grouping variable. So here for every unique group we are finding the `median` for that group.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. If it is okay could you elaborate a little more on how the ave function is working in this case, I am relatively new to R and have not encountered it before.

Comment: Also, I am sorry that I didn't provide a data sample. The data set that I am working with is large and I was trying to be as general as possible as to not give unimportant information. Could you suggest a better way of asking questions for future use?

Comment: @Jamesm131 Hi , I have updated the answer with some description. Do let me know if there is something which is still not clear. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to understand how could you ask a better question.